# Use secret variable sent via REST API

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I currently have an Azure devops pipeline that I trigger with a call to the REST API. I use the "Run pipeline" interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

With this API I can trigger a run of my AZDO pipeline, and I can send variables that are NOT secrets. I can then access these parameters as env variables in the AZDO pipeline.

The format of these variables is defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#variable. Please note the `isSecret` part.

However, I soon as I set `isSecret` to true, I'm unable to read these variables as env variables on the pipeline side. They just appear like they don't contain anything.

I know I could use the library and a variable group to pass secret to the pipeline, but this isn't what I'm trying to do. I'd like to know if I can pass secret to the pipeline via the REST API.

I've been looking around for a few hours and I haven't found anything.

Comment: Hi JPFrancoia; can you show how you are trying to read these variables in the pipeline? Secret variables are very resistant to being used 'incorrectly', so it's worth double-checking what you're trying to do with them.

Comment: Also, here's a bit of useful troubleshooting you can do; declare a [secret variable(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) in the pipeline UI; then you can check whether your difficulties are to do with secret variables in general, or secret variables sent via the REST API.

Comment: Similarly, add a [script task which creates a secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-a-variable-as-secret) and try to use that in a subsequent task. The point being to double-check _the way you're trying to use the secret variable_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting IsSecret to true in API body, the echo output in pipeline will be shown as ***

```
"variables": {"variable 1": { "value": "{Some Vaule}", "isSecret" : true}
```

[image]

If you want to read these variables on pipeline side, you could put your variable into a .txt file and publish the .txt file to Artifacts to check.

If you want to use this API passed secret value as environment variable in your pipeline, you should define it as environment variable first instead of using it directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

[image]

Comment: Yep that did it: "isSecret" : true + mapping the secret variable to an env var (the part in the red rectangle in your image) + the specific syntax for the secret variable (` $(mySecret)`). You really need the 3 things otherwise that doesn't work, and it's kinda hard to guess from the docs. There is little docs about passing *secrets* with the REST API.

Comment: Hi, your understanding is correct. Glad to know it works for you.